# How to deal with different scales of significiance with a lmer model?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, linear-model

I did a linear mixed model and found only one significantly correlated variable. If I do a simple linear model other variables seemed to be correlate.

How is it possible ? Is it because of different scales ?
And is it possible to see all the correlated variables in the linear mixed model ?

Here is the linear mixed model :
nmodel_velocity_ML <- lmer(PC1~ML*TIME_RECORDING + TIME_LAG + TARSUS + BODY_MASS + (1|RING), data = table_pca_normalise, REML = T)
(I have got a warning message : Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling)

Here is the Anova of the linear mixed model :
We see that only the recording time is significantly correlated.
[image: Anova linear mixed model]

Here is the linear model : 
nmodel_velo_ML <- lm(PC1~ML + TIME_LAG + TARSUS + BODY_MASS, data = table_pca_normalise)

And here the Anova of the linear model : We see that ML and Time lag are significantly correlated.
[image: Anova linear model]

Thank you for your help !

Mathilda

Comment: What is the variable `RING` and why didnt you include it as a fixed effect in the linear model ?

Comment: Ring is the identity number of the subject. I divided it into groups so I could have the different time recordings of every ring in a group. So, in every group, there is 6 time recordings (0, 15, 30, 45, 60 and 90 sec) for every identity number. I didn't include it in the linear model because I didn't inclue the time recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are moderate to strong correlations in the repeated measurements within each of the `RING` groups, you should not except statistical inferences to be the same between the linear mixed model analysis that accounts for these correlations and the linear model analysis that does not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have an idea how should I do if I want to see all the correlations in the linear mixed model (with the time recording and the groups) ? And is it right to do it or is it over interpretation ?